# Hautelook Alice: Custom Processor not loading

Tags: symfony, nelmio-alice, alice-fixtures

I am unable to load a custom processor while usinh hautelook/alice-bundle.

In my services.yml:

```
alice.processor.attendance:
    class: MyVendor\MyBundle\DataFixtures\Processor\AttendanceProcessor
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.my_entity_manager","@doctrine.orm.second_entity_manager" ]
    tags: [ { name: hautelook_alice.alice.processor } ]
```

My folder structure in MyVendor/MyBundle:

```
DataFixtures
    | Faker
    | ORM
       | attendance.yml
       | AppFixtures.php
    | Processor
       | AttendanceProcessor.php
```

In the AttendanceProcessor.php:

```
<?php

namespace MyVender\MyBundle\DataFixtures\Processor;

use Nelmio\Alice\ProcessorInterface;
use Isha\HRBundle\Entity\Attendance;

class AttendanceProcessor implements ProcessorInterface
{
    protected $em;
    protected $suvyaEm;

    public function __construct($suvyaEm,$em)
    {
        var_dump("hello3");
        die();
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->suvyaEm = $suvyaEm;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function preProcess($object)
    {
        var_dump("hello1");

        if (false === $object instanceof Attendance) {
            return;
        }

        var_dump("hello1");
        die();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function postProcess($object)
    {
        var_dump("hello2");
        die();
    }
}
```

finally in AppFixtures.php

```
<?php

namespace MyVender\MyBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Hautelook\AliceBundle\Doctrine\DataFixtures\AbstractLoader;
use Isha\HRBundle\DataFixtures\Processor\AttendanceProcessor;
use Nelmio\Alice\Fixtures;

class AppFixtures extends AbstractLoader
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getFixtures()
    {
        return  array(
            __DIR__ . '/attendance.yml',
        );
    }
}
```

but no messages are being output.

Answer (score 0):

The service tag seems to have changed at some point, it works for me when I set the tag `fidry_alice_data_fixtures.processor`.

```
alice.processor.attendance:
    class: MyVendor\MyBundle\DataFixtures\Processor\AttendanceProcessor
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.my_entity_manager","@doctrine.orm.second_entity_manager" ]
    tags: [ { name: fidry_alice_data_fixtures.processor } ]
```